# WinRT serializing a DateTimeOffset

Tags: json, serialization, windows-runtime

I'm working on a Windows 8 Metro application that references a c# WinRT project. Among other things, the c# project makes web requests to an Azure service to perform CRUD operations against a SQL Azure database.

When performing a POST operation on the service, I'm serializing an instance of a class  and putting it in the body of the request.

```
public sealed class Foo
{
    int FooId { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset FooDate { get; set; }
}
```

When this is serialized using the `DataContractJSONSerializer`, the result is something like this:

```
{"FooId":1,"FooDate":{"DateTime":"/Date(1342732970000)/","OffsetMinutes":-420}}
```

FYI that this is 7/19/2012 2:22:50PM -07:00.

OK great ... Only problem is that the Azure service is expecting just a `DateTime`, not a `DateTimeOffset`.  I don't own the Azure service so I can't change its behavior.

So (ignoring that I'm losing the offset) what I need is this to serialize into:

```
{"FooId":1,"FooDate":"/Date(1342732970)/"}
```

My first approach was to add a new aliased `DateTime` property/datamember to the class with a getter that returns the `DateTime` portion of the `DateTimeOffset`.  However, WinRT doesn't support the DateTime type.

There are a couple of hacky ways to get around this, but I wanted to see if there's an elegant way to do this before resorting to one of these:

- Regex on the serialization result before the POST
- String property on the class that returns a JSON formatted date

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing a property on the class with a getter that formats the date appropriately.

I decorated the Foo field with the IgnoreDataMember attribute so that it gets ignored during serialization.  I then added a new field and gave it the alias of Foo for serialization.

Thanks